# Nullpointer deploying web service, returning JaxbElement

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jaxb

my problem, step by step:

- I generated some classes with XJC (from xsd source)
- I write a jaxWs webservice in java
- One of the webmethods has to return a jaxbElement, because one of the xsd havent root element. Return is:

  ```
  JAXBElement<MessageAcknowledgementType> element = new objectFactory().createOTAHotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS(rs);
  Return element;
  ```

WebMethod declaration is:

```
@WebMethod
@WebResult(name="OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRS")
public JAXBElement<MessageAcknowledgementType> modifyHotelRQ(@WebParam(name="OTA_HotelDescriptiveContentNotifRQ")OTAHotelDescriptiveContentNotifRQ rq) {
```

When deploy to tomcat(tomEE), nullpointer exception is launched, but if I change the return to String everything works fine.

I navigate to class `com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.getElementNamespaceURI` and the method `public String getElementLocalName(JAXBElement e)` is receiving a null in "e" when deployment:

```
 public String getElementLocalName(JAXBElement e) {
    return e.getName().getLocalPart();
}
```

Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.getElementNamespaceURI(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:279)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ElementBeanInfoImpl.getElementNamespaceURI(ElementBeanInfoImpl.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.util.ReflectionInvokationHandler.invoke(ReflectionInvokationHandler.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy113.getElementNamespaceURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBSchemaInitializer.begin(JAXBSchemaInitializer.java:225)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:109)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.visitOperation(ServiceModelVisitor.java:130)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.ServiceModelVisitor.walk(ServiceModelVisitor.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:417)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:697)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:214)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfEndpoint.doServiceCreate(CxfEndpoint.java:107)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoEndpoint.<init>(PojoEndpoint.java:89)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:70)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.pojo.PojoWsContainer.createEndpoint(PojoWsContainer.java:45)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfWsContainer.start(CxfWsContainer.java:50)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.cxf.CxfService.createPojoWsContainer(CxfService.java:126)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.webservices.WsService.afterApplicationCreated(WsService.java:417)
    at org.apache.tomee.webservices.TomeeJaxWsService.afterApplicationCreated(TomeeJaxWsService.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$MethodInvocation.invoke(ObserverManager.java:400)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager$InvocationList.invoke(ObserverManager.java:515)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.doFire(ObserverManager.java:111)
    at org.apache.openejb.observer.ObserverManager.fireEvent(ObserverManager.java:100)
    at org.apache.openejb.loader.SystemInstance.fireEvent(SystemInstance.java:135)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.afterStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1661)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help, I lost two entire dayis with this shi......

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Try with @WebResult(name="...",targetNamespace="...", partName="...")